# Download file on AsyncTask or Service?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-service

What would be the best approach for download on Android. You would be using AsyncTask or Service. I see several example being made of two ways, but what would be the best approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not the right question to ask, and the answer may be both.  An AsyncTask is a separate thread of execution.  A Service is just a piece of your app that runs in the background and can live past the end of an Activity.

You need to download any files on a non-UI thread, so either a Thread or AsyncTask is necessary whether you use a Service or not.  So you'll always use one of those two.  The question of whether or not to also use a service is a question of whether you need the file downloaded even if the user goes to another Activity (there's a few other reasons why you may want to use a Service, but this is the main one).

Answer (score 1):

i suggest ,it depends upon the size of file.for small content file ,`asynch` is great but if is gonna be a `longer task` then you can go for `service` because service also comes with `restart feature` (start_sticky) in case user kill your app or your app got killed by the android os(LMK : low memory killer) in case of memory crises